# Compare two Contexts values in android without using `instanceof` or `getclass.getname()`?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

Suppose I have two variable which store Contexts of the corresponding Activities, Is there any way of comparing them such that I can tell if both cotexts are same or not?

Also, I don't want to use `instanceof` OR `getClass().getName()`, because Suppose if the first variable holds context of Activity B, now suppose I went from B to A and now again from A to B and now second variable holds this new Activity B context, now the Comparison should return `false` not `true`?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to compare contexts, what is the goal of doing so?

Comment: to check if they are the same or not?

Comment: What I mean is the problem you're trying to solve is bigger than comparing contexts and there's probably a better way